# Server sockets, multi client, 1 line each

Tags: java, networking

Could someone please give example code of a server socket that connects with multiple client sockets and deals with them sequentially, reading at most one message each from them?

For the reading part, it seems this hangs after reading one line:

```
while ((fromClient = in.readLine()) != null) {
```

and this hangs before reading anything:

```
fromClient = in.readLine();
```

Comment: Using `readLine()` only works if you know that the message you are reading is in plaintext and will be terminated by a newline character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `while` to `if`. `readLine()` blocks until a complete line has been read or the peer has closed the connection. If that's blocking trying to read just one line, it calls your rather strange requirement into question. If one client is slow it will slow down the entire system. Are you sure you need to do this? You do realize that you can read from all clients simultaneously via threads?

Comment: I ended up forcing myself to multithread, since it's really the norm. It works. Sorry others who tried to satisfy my strange requirement: thanks anyway it was food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something more like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/Nonblockserver.htm). But I'm afraid you're going to need to separate the network logic from your program's logic to a greater extent.

That is, you need to use `java.nio` to accomplish this, because calling `readLine()` will block on the read until the end of the line is reached. (so if you want to use `readLine()`, you'll need a thread per client)

You'll probably have to extend the example to keep a buffer per client and monitor it for the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the oracle examples?

Server:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockServer.java

Client:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockClient.java

Description:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: I believe that example is 1 server, 1 client. I have 1 server, multiple clients. They do also have such an example, but there's is multithreaded while mine has no need to be.